# listview issue while showing control inside in it?

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a user control and one button and one dropdownlist(ddl1) and a listview in my content page.

the user control consist of 3 dropdownlist.

Now the issue is that when i show image in listview based on ddl1. It works fine but when selected index change occurs in dropdownlist of user control then sometime the image control appears in listview without image which shouldn't.

http://img560.imageshack.us/i/listviewerror.png/

what could be issue because of which listview shows last control generated inside the listview?

suppose last time if listview showed 2 image and if i try to change something in user control's dropdownlist then it will show two image control but withou the image...

please guide me where am i going wrong??

if required i will post the code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to bind the listview again when select the value from droupdown list. then may be you are not face the same problem.

hope this help.